# Django: Invalid block tag on line 41: 'endblock', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

Tags: django, django-templates

I am working on a project right now, particularly on the CRUD phase. I am also new on the Django framework, but I knew some basic stuff about it. I did everything stated on the manual but it's weird because I got this kind of error.

I am using Django 2.2. Here's my code, by the way.

> base.html

```
    <!-- base.html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">  
        <title>{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}: CAO-SMS Admin</title>

        {% load static %}
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'fisher_prof/style.css' %}"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block body %}Body{% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

> list.html

```
    <!-- Displays the whole database (fisher) -->

    {% extends 'fisher_prof/base.html' %}

    {% block title %} Fisher's Information {% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
        <br>
        <center>
        <h1>Fisher's Database</h1>
        <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead class = "thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID&nbsp&nbsp</th>
                    <th>Fisher's Last Name</th>
                    <th>Fisher's First Name</th>
                    <th>Fisher's Middle Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile Number</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            {% for fisher in fishers %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{fisher.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{fisher.first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{fisher.mid_name}}</td>
                <td>{{fisher.cell_num}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <br> <br>
            </center>
    {% endblock %}
```

Then when I run it, Django tells me this:

> Invalid block tag on line 41: 'endblock', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Is there something wrong with my code? I really need help.

Comment: I've just tried this template and everything looks ok. Are you sure the error is from this template? `list.html` has only 34 lines. For me this error appears when I remove `{% endfor %}` but it states the error is line 33 - which is expected

Comment: `for` block seems to be valid. Probably this is not the full source or the wrong template (error happens elsewhere). Also templates can be  cached - try to restart app and clear cache (restart memcached/redis/etc or remove cache files if filestorage used).

Comment: @AdrianKrupa I will try to clear the cache, as suggested by Ivan, because this code worked before. Maybe it has to do with the cache.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I think I know the "main" problem. For some reason {% endfor %} is not recognized. So if that's the case, the closing tag for {% for fisher in fishers %} is somewhat missing

Comment: Try rewriting this block in different ways. Maybe there is some illegal symbol like zero-width space. There is no obvious flaw here, so keep debugging.